# How do I make a sphere become transparent when it is outside of a box that is transparent and have the sphere visible when inside the transparent box?

Tags: objects

Consider:

[image]

How would I make a sphere transparent when it is outside of a box that is transparent and have the sphere be visible when it is inside the transparent box?

Answer (score 12):

## For Cycles: [Sphere Material setup]

### This verson invalid in other side

[image]

## This verson valid for all side

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://www.screentogif.com/  ;)  this is an elegant solution

Comment: Can't you plug directly the *Is transmission ray* into the alpha input since it's a 0/1 value ?